# Battery drain issue while using iBeacons in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I am developing an iOS7+ application with `iBeacon` technology(Using  estimote sdk 2.3.2). Now i am facing device battery drain issue while the app is running in foreground and background.
Has any option for ranging `iBeacons` without using `CLLocationManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to range `iBeacons` is to use `CoreLocation`, and unfortunately it is very power consuming.

However, you can turn on the `Ranging` only when you need it. `Monitoring` consumes much less energy and it is enough to find out if you are in `iBeacon` range.

I have implemented a logic to store found `iBeacons` with time when I last saw them. When `Monitoring` informs me that I have met new `iBeacon` (it can be an old one if we had left his range and went near it again) I start `Ranging`:

```
- (void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region { 
    [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}
```

and then in method method:

```
- (void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region { 

}
```

I'm checking if I have seen this beacon within last hour. If I had I ignore it, and if not I do my logic. After that I'm stopping `Ranging`:

```
[self.beaconManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

And then only `Monitoring` is checking for new `iBeacons`.